# Bootstrap select dropdown does not open menu on Windows machines - IE, Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, windows

Building atop [Silvio Moreto's Bootstrap Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/) I have a custom dropdown with no issues in Chrome, Firefox and Safari on Mac, iOS and Android (private browsing or not).

#### Windows

In Windows the select renders how visually expected -- everything looks to be in place -- but clicking the select does not open the dropdown menu (which is kind of the point).

I'm really stumped and surprised that the operating system could have such an impact on this component. I also have little experience working with Windows machines and hope someone may be able to give some clues about what could be happening.

[image: example of working select dropdown]

#### Live example

[View the problem in real time here](https://matchtest.talkspace.com/introduction?s=63)

Has anyone experienced a similar problem? How could this happen?

Comment: It doesn't work on my Mac either (macOS Sierra, Chrome), so you can rule out Windows being the issue right off the bat.

Comment: It's broken in every Mac browser I've tested - I actually haven't seen it working anywhere. Clicking the dropdown toggles an `.active` class on it, but there's CSS missing to unhide the menu when that class is present. Are you sure this didn't coincidentally break before you tested it on Windows?

Comment: Also, the original code you based on still works on IE/Windows 7 where your derived work does not.  It would be more helpful if you had a fiddler or something where we could see the original markup.  Feels like there is something wrong there.

Comment: Okay cool let me see if there is some discrepancy between cached versions of the CSS and the actual code -- will report back and open a try opening a fiddle if this does not indicate the issue.